# Why the name authors aren't equally spaced in `eqparbox` package?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

On the cover it is all perfect, but on the cover sheet the first one is more spaced.

```
\title{MWE align author}
  \documentclass[
      12pt,
      openright,ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
      twoside,
      a4paper,
      english,
      french,   
      spanish,
      brazil, 
      oneside
      ]{abntex2}  

  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
  \usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
  \usepackage{titling}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox}


  \renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
  \renewcommand{\backref}{}
  \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
      \ifcase #1 %
          Nenhuma citação no texto.%
      \or
          Citado na página #2.%
      \else
          Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
      \fi}%
  \titulo{Modelo Canônico de\\ Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico com \abnTeX}

  \autor{\eqmakebox[Name][r]{Name One} \qquad \eqmakebox[number][l]{number1} \\
          \eqmakebox[Name][r]{Another Name} \qquad \eqmakebox[number][l]{number2} \\
          \eqmakebox[Name][r]{Other Name} \qquad \eqmakebox[number][l]{Other Number}}

  \local{São Carlos}
  \data{2017}
  \tipotrabalho{Relatório técnico}
  \preambulo{Modelo canônico de Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico em conformidade
  com as normas ABNT apresentado à comunidade de usuários \LaTeX.}

  \definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

  \makeatletter
  \hypersetup{
          pdftitle={\@title},
          pdfauthor={\@author},
          pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
          pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
          pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{relatório técnico},
          colorlinks=true,
          linkcolor=blue,
          citecolor=blue,
          filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=blue,
          bookmarksdepth=4
  }
  \makeatother
  \setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

  \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
  \makeindex

  \begin{document}

  \selectlanguage{brazil}

  \frenchspacing

  \imprimircapa

  \imprimirfolhaderosto*

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you unify the usage of `\\` after your `eqmakebox` you get the same spacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{abntex2}  

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\titulo{title}
\autor{%
\eqmakebox[Name][r]{Name One } \qquad \eqmakebox[number][l]{number1}\\
\eqmakebox[Name][r]{Another N} \qquad \eqmakebox[number][l]{number2}\\
\eqmakebox[Name][r]{Other Nam} \qquad \eqmakebox[number][l]{Other Num}\\
}

\local{São Carlos}
\data{2017}
\tipotrabalho{Relatório técnico}

\begin{document}

  \imprimirfolhaderosto*

\end{document}
```